# Oracle query performance degrades over time

Tags: oracle

We have a oracle query which starts experiencing performance degradation after some time.

Let me clarify the situation:

1. we find that the query is experiencing performance issue.
2. someone works on the issue and checks whats wrong. everything looks ok (e.g. the joins, explain plans, indexes, gather stats, DBAs review the query).
3. everything is found to be ok.
4. DBA consults SQL Tuning advisor & forces a new plan
5. query performance improves by 80 to 90 % .
6. Everyone is happy
7. after a around 40 to 60 days the issue returns :)

The above scenario has repeated twice.

This issue has been noticed only in UAT and PROD in one of the locations (deployments) but not in other. 
Just to clarify, the issue seems to be with query/db side as we have noticed using Dynatrace.

Comment: Unfortunately, the lack of details provided make this question unclear (and very broad, and opinion-soliciting around approach to solving this type of problem). As written, it's off topic and will likely be closed. You haven't provided any query details. We don't know if your database is static or growing. We basically know nothing aside from the general approach your devs and DBA follow.

Comment: Also, if this is not about programming, you might better ask at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You may need to run gather stats / rebuild index regularly.

Comment: I'm guessing something is going wrong in step #2.  In my experience SQL Tuning Adviser is not very clever and most Oracle developers and DBAs can usually find something that it can't.  If you're constantly getting outsmarted by the tuning adviser you need to either try harder or ask some different developers and DBAs.  (Or post the details here.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a statistics data issue. The statistics data might be stale after a period of time. You/your DBA needs to setup a job the keep the statistics data updated.

Alternatively, you may use a kind of SQL Tuning tool (e.g. one can be get from www.sqlfast.com) to check the performance bottleneck when the problem happens, that might indicate which object need to be further investigated, and you can take proper action.